# NAudio Skip Forward and Skip Back using MixingWaveProvider32

Tags: c#, audio, mp3, naudio

I'm attempting to build a multitrack player using NAudio.

I've managed to load 4 MP3s and play them in sync.

```
using NAudio.Wave;
using NAudio_Test.Properties;
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace NAudio_Test
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public WaveOut outputDevice1;
        public MixingWaveProvider32 waveProvider;
        public AudioFileReader audioFile1;
        public AudioFileReader audioFile2;
        public AudioFileReader audioFile3;
        public AudioFileReader audioFile4;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lbDirectory.Text = Settings.Default.StartingDirectory;
            lbFile.Text = Settings.Default.File;
        }


        private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            outputDevice1?.Stop();
        }

        private void OnPlaybackStopped(object sender, StoppedEventArgs args)
        {
            outputDevice1?.Dispose();
            outputDevice1 = null;

            audioFile1?.Dispose();
            audioFile2?.Dispose();
            audioFile3?.Dispose();
            audioFile4?.Dispose();

            audioFile1 = null;
            audioFile2 = null;
            audioFile3 = null;
            audioFile4 = null;
        }

        private void btnPlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string file1 = lbDirectory.Text + "\\" + lbFile.Text + "_1.mp3";
            string file2 = lbDirectory.Text + "\\" + lbFile.Text + "_2.mp3";
            string file3 = lbDirectory.Text + "\\" + lbFile.Text + "_3.mp3";
            string file4 = lbDirectory.Text + "\\" + lbFile.Text + "_4.mp3";
            Console.WriteLine(file1);
            Console.WriteLine(file2);
            Console.WriteLine(file3);
            Console.WriteLine(file4);

            audioFile1 = new AudioFileReader(file1);
            audioFile2 = new AudioFileReader(file2);
            audioFile3 = new AudioFileReader(file3);
            audioFile4 = new AudioFileReader(file4);

            waveProvider = new MixingWaveProvider32(new IWaveProvider[] { audioFile1, audioFile2, audioFile3, audioFile4 });
            outputDevice1 = new WaveOut();
            outputDevice1.Init(waveProvider);
            outputDevice1.Play();
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried a few ways of forwarding the playback but the best success was with

```
 private void btnFwd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            outputDevice1?.Stop();
            
            Console.WriteLine(audioFile1.CurrentTime.ToString());
            audioFile1.CurrentTime = audioFile1.CurrentTime + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
            audioFile2.CurrentTime = audioFile2.CurrentTime + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
            audioFile3.CurrentTime = audioFile3.CurrentTime + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
            audioFile4.CurrentTime = audioFile4.CurrentTime + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
            Console.WriteLine(audioFile1.CurrentTime.ToString());
            outputDevice1?.Play();
        }
```

but with this method I get

```
 07:04:52:409   Exception thrown: 'NAudio.MmException' in NAudio.WinMM.dll
 07:04:52:409   Exception thrown: 'NAudio.MmException' in NAudio.WinMM.dll
```

I know I'm probably oversimplifying the process and need to do more with the MixingWaveProvider32 but I can't find how. I've looked all over for samples of this kind of problem but can't find any. If anyone can point me in the right direction, I would be thankful.

Comment: What is the exception message? Also, `MixingSampleProvider` would be preferable to `MixingWaveProvider32` from a performance perspective

Comment: @MarkHeath Thank you. I have changed  MixingWaveProvider32 since posting the question and made a few other changes and along the way the error was fixed.
I'm still getting a `Exception thrown: 'System.FormatException' in NAudio.Core.dll`
When `TrackReader = new Mp3FileReader(TrackFileName); Channel = new WaveChannel32(TrackReader);` runs. But it does not seem to affect the running of the program.